# subscription.listener.apply is not a function (react-native iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Whenever I am opening the app for the first time from Testflight, the app crashes with the following error.

```
TypeError: subscription.listener.apply is not a function. (In 'subscription.listener.apply(subscription.context, args)', 'subscription.listener.apply' is undefined)
```

This is not happening in debug mode, and happens only during the first install from TestFlight, after the first crash it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my issue was that I was not using Linking of react-native package  correctly.

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);

const handleOpenURL = async () => {
 ...
}
```

In my above code, the handleOpenURL is an async function which was causing the issue. Removing the async resolved the issue.

```
const handleOpenURL = () => {
     ...
}
```

I still have to figure out why this issue was not crashing my Android app, and also this issue was fine in react-native 0.64, but started crashing in iOS when I updated react-native to latest 0.66.4.